# Unable to Install Packages After Upgrade to 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, nodejs

I'm trying to install nodejs, however I get the follow error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: python-minimal but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then when trying to install python-minimal it fails, and says python2-minimal replaces. Python2-minimal is already the newest version

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Returns with

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The command:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

Does not list any output.

Any suggestions?

sudo apt update output

```
Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bionic InRelease
Fetched 101 kB in 0s (254 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

sudo apt upgrade output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Full sudo apt-get install nodejs output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: python-minimal but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Additional output included @user535733

Comment: `https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bionic InRelease`: Is installing 18.04 (bionic) node packages onto a 20.04 (focal) system intentional?

Comment: I imagine not, I wasn't the one who updated it.

Comment: Try updating that source to 'focal', then `sudo apt update` (since your sources changed), then try installing node again.